# Wpf/Silverlight: How to convert hex value into Color?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I know how to create a SolidColorBrush of color blue and return it like this within a converter:

```
return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

However what if I needed the SolidColorBrush to be of this Hex value? `#44FFFF00` ?

How do I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x44, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0));
```

([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb.aspx))

Note: Don't use `Color.FromRgb()` (without the A) if your code will be shared in both Silverlight and WPF, as the FromRgb method doesn't exist in Silverlight.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
(Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#44FFFF00"));
```

much better IMHO

Comment: For those of you that (like me) didn't have the namespaces already, here it is fully spelled out. (System.Windows.Media.Brush)(new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#44FFFF00"));

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x44FFFF00));
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Silverlight: *No overload for method 'FromArgb' takes 1 arguments*.